# Spark driver pod with Kubernetes not restarting even after restart policy: Always

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am running spark-submit with in my kubernetes cluster. As per spark documentation I am creating a pod template and specifying restart policy `Always`. Below is my pod template.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pi-exampe
spec:
  restartPolicy: Always

Command:
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master k8s://https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=com/synchronoss/sip/<mySparkImage> --conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=file:///tmp --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile=driver-template.yaml   --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=driver-template.yaml  local:///opt/sip/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.2.jar
```

After spark submit initially pod is launched. However when I am deleting the pod with `kubectl delete pod <podname>` I dont see pod restarting again.

I am looking for restartability of the pod if It fails for some reason.

Comment: You appear to have a misunderstanding of what the difference is between "restart" and `kubectl delete pod` -- the latter tells kubernetes to recreate all containers, assign a new Pod name, Pod IP, and reschedule it. The former is what happens if you `kubectl exec $pod -- kill -9 1`, which leaves the Pod name, IP, and scheduling intact

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use kubectl exec $pod -- kill -9 1 on my docker image. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding points by referring to spark documentation again :

It is important to note that Spark is opinionated about certain pod configurations so there are values in the pod template that will always be overwritten by Spark. Therefore, users of this feature should note that specifying the pod template file only lets Spark start with a template pod instead of an empty pod during the pod-building process. For details, see the full list of pod template values that will be overwritten by spark.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template-properties